# Is there a voting plugin available for rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

acts_as_voteable and vote_fu don't work on rails 3. Is there one that does work?

Answer (score 3):

They are very simple to set up. Here's one you can start with :

```
class Object < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many    :votes, :as => :votable
   has_many    :voting_users,
               :through => :votes,
               :source => :user

#object_controller

  def vote_up
    get_vote
    @vote.value += 1 unless @vote.value == 1
    @vote.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {render :action => 'view'}
      format.js { render :action => 'vote'}
    end
  end

  private

  def get_vote
    current_object = Objects.detect{|r| r.id == params[:id].to_i}
    @object = current_object
    @vote = current_object.votes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
    unless @vote
      @vote = Vote.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :value => 0)
      current_object.votes << @vote
    end
  end
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the code. We'll probably take it somewhere in this direction.

Comment: I was in the same place and couldn't find gems so just wrote this.

Answer (score 2):

There's also [vote_fu](https://github.com/peteonrails/vote_fu) and v[ote_fu_rails3](https://github.com/vshvedov/vote_fu_rails_3).

Answer (score 1):

[Make_votable](https://github.com/medihack/make_voteable) looks like an awesome and easily implemented gem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Thumbs Up](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up/) and it works like a charm. It's an adaptation of vote_fu to Rails 3.